# Upgrading to SQL Server 2008 from SQL Server 2005, will there any error in JAVA application?

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I am going to use SQL SERVER 2008 for a JAVA application. The application is currently running on SQL Server 2005.

Will there be any problem? Will I get any syntax related error or all my SQL queries will work perfectly?

Comment: if it's just CRUD I don't think there will be an error.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [SQL Server 2008 Upgrade Advisor](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11455) to identify feature and configuration changes that might affect your upgrade. Though this wouldn't give you a definitive "it will work" it can give you an idea of what might be wrong.